# Add point markers in QGIS 3.4 without coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, markers

I am new to QGIS and trying to insert svg markers into a map I've been creating. I am struggling to find resources on my exact problem. I read about creating a new georeferenced shapefile and layering it on top of my original map but I am unsure if that is the way to go. Also, the symbols I will want to insert do not have GPS coordinates, but I want to do it roughly by eyeballing. Can someone suggest a procedure or perhaps other useful posts / videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a point layer (`Layer -> create layer -> new shape layer`), toggle editing on, then set your points where you want your markers to be. Save the editing, then access the point-layer's properties by either double-clicking it or right-clicking it and choosing `properties`.

Go to the `symbology`-tab and change your layer-type from `simple marker` to `SVG-marker`, then select an appropriate symbol.

[image]

Comment: Toggle editing again and choose the `node tool` in the editing-toolbox, then you may drag the points around

Comment: The relevant **Properties** tab now appears to be called **Symbology**